# CSS: how to add top level div to php code

Tags: php, css

This function runs several time and with MyClass-div I end up with several text blocks. I want to put the content together in a div tat can be centered.

```
function MyFunction() {
echo '<p class="MyClass">Text: </p>';
$terms = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'pa_stilart');
foreach($terms as $term){
echo '<p class="MyClass"><a href="/link/'.$term->slug.'"> <u>'.$term->name.'</u></a></p>';
}
}
```

Comment: Just output a `<div class="someClass>` at the beginning of the function and a `</div>` at the end...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add  style for ParentClass to center the content

```
    function MyFunction() {
    //add new 
    echo '<div class="ParentClass">';

    echo '<p class="MyClass">Text: </p>';
    $terms = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'pa_stilart');
    foreach($terms as $term){
    echo '<p class="MyClass"><a href="/link/'.$term->slug.'"> <u>'.$term->name.'</u></a></p>';
    }

    echo '</div">';
}
```